# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Unknown Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

When my application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk tries to call quicksight through the AWS JAVA SDK, I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: quicksight.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com`.

When I ssh into the underlying EC2 instance, `ping` is unable to resolve the host either

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ ping quicksight.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
ping: unknown host quicksight.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

I cannot resolve this by editing `/etc/hosts`, because this is an auto-scaling environment.

I checked the security groups, but all outbound traffic appears to be allowed.
[image]

I checked the VPC, but DNS Resolution and HostNames are enabled, and beanstalk environments in the VPC can resolve hosts.
[image]

Does anyone know what else this could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was creating the Quicksight client without specifying the Region

```
quickSightClient = QuickSightClient.create() // this was the problem
```

So, it was defaulting to the default region of the authenticated user, which locally was `US-East-1`, but EC2 prod instance was in `CA-Central-1`, which doesn't have quicksight endpoints.  So it was not resolving because the host actually does not exist.

I tried to define the following environment variable, `AWS_REGION=us-east-1`, in the Elastic Beanstalk console; but I could not get that to work.  It didn't seem to make a difference

So, instead, I explicitly set the region in my code.

```
quickSightClient = QuickSightClient.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).build()
```

Problem solved!